# Stay login in React Native WebView with expo on ios

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

In my react native expo app I have two screens,

One for login page where the user will put the credentials and after successful login, it will be redirected to the webview page.

Inside webpage, I’m trying to get the home page content but it's getting redirected to the index page(web login page) in `ios`. But in android after using `domStorageEnabled={true}` I’m getting home page.

How can I get the home page only using app login without login from the index page(web page login)? Please provide a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If logging in to the `app` is the same as logging in to the `web`, log in to the `app` and send it to the `web`.

```js
const logindata = {id: id, password: password}
jsCode = `loginfunction(logindata)`; //it is web function
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://example.com'}}
        injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. When the user login, they will get a token_id. When I put a uri: `http://example.com/login-id/token_id/details` in `Linking` component, it will direct me to the web version without asking for login. This doesn't work with `WebView`. I tried your method and it doesn't work. How to solve?